# Show preimage is a circle

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $f:S^3 \rightarrow S^2$ be $f(w,x,y,z) = (w^2+x^2-y^2-z^2, 2wz+2xy, 2xz-2wy)$. Show that $f^{-1}(y)$ is a circle where $y \in S^2$, and that $f$ is a submersion.

I calculated the differential $df_x$ but had no idea how to attack the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the [Hopf fibration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_fibration).
To see this, we consider in the notations of *loc. cit.* 
$$
\begin{aligned}
(w,x,y,z) &\leftrightarrow (\ x+iw,\ z+iy\ )=(\ z_0,\ z_1\ )\ ,\\
f(w,x,y,z) &\leftrightarrow p(\ x+iw,\ z+iy\ )=p(z_0,z_1)
\\
&:=(\ |z_0|^2-|z_1|^2\ ,\ 2z_0\bar z_1\ )\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
The first component above,
$|z_0|^2-|z_1|^2$, is a real number, the second one, 
$2z_0\bar z_1$, is a complex number, and computed explicitly its real and imaginary part are:
$$
2z_0\bar z_1=2(x+iw)(z+iy) = 2(xz-wy)+2i(wz+xy)\ .
$$

---

Now, as mentioned in *loc. cit.*, if in the new notations two points $(z_0,z_1)$ and $(w_0,w_1)$ map via $p$ in the same point $\in S^2$, i.e.
$$
p(z_0,z_1)=p(w_0,w_1)\ ,
$$
then there is a complex number of modulus one, $u$ say, with $(w_0,w_1)=(uz_0,uz_1)$. Indeed...

The case $z_0=0$
is simple. We obtain $z_1\ne 0$, and from $-1=|z_0|^2-|z_1|^2=|w_0|^2-|w_1|^2$,
so $w_0=0$ and $|w_1|=1$. Now take $u=w_1/z_1$.

The case $z_1=0$
is similar. We obtain $z_0\ne 0$, and from $+1=|z_0|^2-|z_1|^2=|w_0|^2-|w_1|^2$,
we get $|w_0|=1$ and $w_1=0$. Now take $u=w_0/z_0$.

The remained case is the case with $z_0,z_1,w_0,w_1\ne 0$.
Let $u$ be the number $u=w_0/z_0\ne 0$. Then from $z_0\bar z_1=w_0\bar w_1$ we get
$\bar u^{-1}=w_1/z_1$. Now 
$$
|z_0|^2-|z_1|^2 =
|w_0|^2-|w_1|^2 =
|u|^2\;|z_0|^2-|u|^{-2}|z_1|^2 \ ,
$$
So 
$$
|z_0|^2(1-|u|^2) = 
|z_1|^2(1-|u|^{-2}) \ ,
$$
which implies $|u|=1$, else we have different signs in the equality.

---

We have a fibration, the fiber is parametrized by a complex number $u$ of modulus one, and in this sense "the preimage of each point in $S^2$ is a circle". (This is in particular a submersion.)